# I have a question about the "sed" statement in bash (macOS)

Tags: bash, macos, sed, scripting

I'm just starting to play around with (bash/zsh) shell scripting in macOS. I'm experiencing an issue with the "sed" statement:

I have set the following variable

```
var1=MACBOOKPRO
```

when executing the following terminal command:

```
echo $var1 | sed -- 's/IMAC/IM/g; s/IMACPRO/IMP/g; s/MACMINI/MM/g; s/MACMINIPRO/MMP/g; s/MACBOOK/MB/g; s/MACBOOKAIR/MBA/g; s/MACBOOKPRO/MBP/g; s/MACPRO/MP/g; s/POWERMAC/PM/g'
```

The following output is produced: `MBPRO` (which is not what I want)

But when using the following command:

```
echo $var1 | sed -- 's/MACBOOKPRO/MBP/g; s/IMAC/IM/g; s/IMACPRO/IMP/g; s/MACMINI/MM/g; s/MACMINIPRO/MMP/g; s/MACPRO/MP/g; s/MACBOOKAIR/MBA/g; s/MACBOOK/MB/g; s/POWERMAC/PM/g'
```

I get a different (but correct output)! - `MBP`

Has anyone have a clue for me why this is happening?

Thanks in advance for your reply
Charly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it performs the replacements in the order you specify them. Your variable matches both `/MACBOOK/` and `/MACBOOKPRO/`. When the first pattern is earlier in the list, it replaces the `MACBOOK` prefix with `MB`.

When you have overlapping patterns like this, you should put the longer ones first.

Another option is to change your patterns so they're anchored to match the entire string, using `^` and `$`:

```
echo $var1 | sed -- 's/^IMAC$/IM/g; s/^IMACPRO$/IMP/g; s/^MACMINI$/MM/g; s/^MACMINIPRO$/MMP/g; s/^MACBOOK$/MB/g; s/^MACBOOKAIR$/MBA/g; s/^MACBOOKPRO$/MBP/g; s/^MACPRO$/MP/g; s/^POWERMAC$/PM/g'
```

Comment: Barmar, thanks for your quick answer. Unfortunately the 2nd answer/suggestion does give me an error (tuning maCOS Mojave):
```sed: 1: "s/^IMAC$/IM/g; s$/IMACP ...": bad flag in substitute command: '/'```

Comment: Sorry, I messed up when I tried to automate adding all the ^ and $.

Comment: Edited the answer to fix it.

Comment: Thanks Barmar,

The reason  had was to have kinda alphabetical listed, so I have just reversed it:
```echo $var1 | sed -- 's/POWERMAC/PM/g; s/MACPRO/MP/g; s/MACBOOKPRO/MBP/g; s/MACBOOKAIR/MBA/g; s/MACBOOK/MB/g; s/MACMINIPRO/MMP/g; s/MACMINI/MM/g; s/IMACPRO/IMP/g; s/IMAC/IM/g;';)```

This worked and it's the way I like.

Answer (score 0):

`s/MACBOOK/MB/g;` turns `MACBOOKPRO` into `MBPRO`.

Comment: you might add to your answer, that the patterns are applied in the sequence that they are specified.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27738655)

Comment: @gdogg371 please learn what the NAA flag means.